# WPF a Multibinding on ColumnDefinitions

Tags: wpf, multibinding

I have a `Grid` that holds segments such as:

```
--
  ---
      -----------
                 ---
                    -------------------
```

Each segment's visual length is dependant upon the total length, and its position depends upon the end of the previous segment.

I have a `MultiBinding` to achieve this, that calculates Width of 3 `ColumnDefinition`.

I first thought I'd calculate the entire `ColumnDefinitions` so that each item is placed correctly, but as it happens, the compiler doesn't allow me to bind Grid.ColumnDefinitions, i.e you can't do this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource yourConverter}">
            <Binding Path=firstValueForCalculus />
            <Binding Path=secondValueForCalculus />
            ...   
     </MultiBinding>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

So now, I'm thinking my only option is to make 3 `IMultiValueConverters`, bind each of the 3 `ColumnDefinition.Width` to their respective converter, and calculate everything... but that sounds very nasty and my "Oh-My-God-You're-Going-Down" alarm rang.

Any idea to do this elegantly?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Yurek's code a bit modified : (Is that what you meant? or did I destroy it? :p)

```
public class GridHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnDefinitionsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnDefinitions", typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection), typeof(GridHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(
            (sender, e) => 
            {
                var element = sender as Grid;
                if (element != null)
                {
                    element.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
                    foreach (ColumnDefinition col in (IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition>)e.NewValue)
                    {
                        element.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
                    }
                    //element.ColumnDefinitions.AddRange((IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition>)e.NewValue);
                }
            })));


        public static IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> GetColumnDefinitions(Grid element)
        {
            return (IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition>)element.GetValue(ColumnDefinitionsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetColumnDefinitions(Grid element, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> columnDefinitions)
        {
            element.SetValue(ColumnDefinitionsProperty, columnDefinitions);
        }
    }
```

Comment: We should define the "elegance", first. Anyway, could you explain better what's the source of the widths?

Comment: It's an audio file split into parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set ColumnDefinitions using binding because it is read only. But there is an elegant solution - to use attched dependency property.

```
public class GridHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnDefinitionsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnDefinitions", typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection), typeof(GridHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
            (sender, e) =>
            {
                var element = sender as Grid;
                if(element != null)
                {
                     element.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
                     element.ColumnDefinitions.AddRange((IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition>)e.NewValue);
                }
            }));

        public static IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> GetColumnDefinitions(Grid element)
        {
            return (IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition>)element.GetValue(ColumnDefinitionsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetColumnDefinitions(Grid element, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> columnDefinitions)
        {
            element.SetValue(ColumnDefinitionsProperty, columnDefinitions);
        }
    }
```

Now you can use binding for column definitions creation:

```
<Grid>
     <local:GridHelper.ColumnDefinitions>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource yourConverter}">
            <Binding Path=firstValueForCalculus />
            <Binding Path=secondValueForCalculus />
            ...   
        </MultiBinding>
     </local:GridHelper.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I get an error telling me that ColumnDefinitions does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' =/ this looks cool though!

Comment: I replaced it with foreach (ColumnDefinition col in (ColumnDefinitionCollection)e.NewValue)
                     {
                         element.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col);
                     }

Comment: Now on first test, the compiler gives me an error that says ColumnDefinitionCollection has no constructors defined, also, in XAML local:GridHelper.ColumnDefinitions is not an option, I only get attached:GridHelper.InputBindings

Comment: Please see my updated question, where I had to modify your code a bit (putting code in comments is messed up...)

Comment: GetColumnDefinitions and SetColumnDefinitions are never called, and whichever collection of columndefinition i return in my converter make no difference in the end =/

Comment: please check wether PropertyChangedCallback is called, xaml parser doesn't not call SetColumnDefinitions directly.

Comment: typeof(ColumnDefinitionCollection) should be replaced to typeof(IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition>).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your audio file can be split in several parts, so an array.

I would create a collection of ColumnDefinition, each one having a width function of the audio part. Then the collection can be assigned to the Grid's ColumnDefinitions property.

EDIT: I forgot that the Grid property is read-only. So, you may add/remove the items runtime.